# Как задать кастомные поля только для одной странице в WordPress без плагинов?

Tags: wordpress

Добрый вечер. Выбрал страницу и загрузил шаблон( к примеру template-order.php) где пишу весь код. Вывел что мне надо, и есть 4 текста, которые не связанны ни логикой ни структурой. Я бы хотел , дабы удобнее было, когда администратор нажимает на страницу и там открывается редактирование страницы, под описанием страницы было бы 4 кастомных поля( textare) где бы пользователь писал и я бы выводил текст. Кастомные поля нужны только тут и грузить плагин нет смысла. Можно ли как то самому сделать через functions.php

Comment: Стоит уточнить - это будет всего одна такая страница на сайте или их может быть не ограниченно с таким шаблоном. Это точно  [шаблон темы](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-page) или же  [шаблон страницы](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B#.D0.A8.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.BD.D1.8B_.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.86)?  (PS. `template` в имени надеюсь как пример, а не реальное название файла? Я бы не рисковал так называть шаблоны)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте такой код в functions.php

```
function my_properties_add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'my_properties_additional',
        'Дополнительное поле',
        'my_properties_meta_box_callback',
        'page'
    );
    add_meta_box(
        'my_properties_additional_2',
        'Дополнительное поле 2',
        'my_properties_meta_box_callback_2',
        'page'
    );
}

function my_properties_meta_box_callback( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_properties_meta_box', 'my_properties_meta_box_nonce' );
    $creds                       = array();
    $creds['my_properties'] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_properties', true );
    ?>
    <div>
        <?php
        wp_editor( $creds['my_properties'], 'my_properties', array(
            'textarea_rows' => 9,
        ) );
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}

function my_properties_meta_box_callback_2( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_properties_meta_box', 'my_properties_meta_box_nonce_2' );
    $creds                       = array();
    $creds['my_properties'] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_properties_2', true );
    ?>
    <div>
        <?php
        wp_editor( $creds['my_properties'], 'my_properties_2', array(
            'textarea_rows' => 9,
        ) );
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_properties_add_meta_box' );

function my_properties_meta_box_save( $post_id ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( ! ( isset( $_POST['my_properties_meta_box_nonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my_properties_meta_box_nonce'], 'my_properties_meta_box' ) ) ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( ! ( isset( $_POST['my_properties_meta_box_nonce_2'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my_properties_meta_box_nonce_2'], 'my_properties_meta_box' ) ) ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' === $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_properties', $_POST['my_properties'] );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_properties_2', $_POST['my_properties_2'] );
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'my_properties_meta_box_save' );
```

Он добавляет 2 метабокса в админку редактирования страницы. Вы сами сможете увеличить кол-во с 2 до 4.

Код рабочий, проверил на своем тестовом сайте.

Так это выглядит в админке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У ТСа задача задать только для одного шаблона, а на остальных чтобы не было :) ЗЫ. в коде затесалась лишняя табуляция в  2х местах где `$creds`

Comment: А, да, для одной страницы. С утра добавлю if ))

Comment: Добавил с вечера )