# Произвольные поля категорий/постов

Tags: wordpress

На сайте есть категории (Москва, Самара, УФА ...). Необходимо при выборе "Москва", вывести список метро Москвы. Решил делать так, к каждой категории создать произвольное поле со списком станций метро.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: При выборе где? На сайте, в админке, в категории, на странице?

Comment: В категории и при создании поста

Comment: @KAGG Design, хотел сделать через описание категории, но нельзя трогать стандартный функционал. Можно как-нибудь сделать такое же поле, как описание категории?

Comment: Все можно. Эта штука с категориями называется метабокс. Посмотрите вот этот мой ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/755756/220220

Comment: @KAGG Design, а не подскажите, как тоже самое добавить к категориям, и как потом их выводить? Буду очень благодарен

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/adding-custom-meta-boxes-to-wordpress/

Comment: @KAGG Design, Спасибо за подсказку! В итоге сделал как здесь написано  https://wp-kama.ru/question/meta-i-title-dlya-rubrik